# Mathematical representation of a set of points in N dimensional space?

Tags: math, machine-learning, feature-extraction, data-representation

Given some x data points in an N dimensional space, I am trying to find a fixed length representation that could describe any subset s of those x points? For example the mean of the s subset could describe that subset, but it is not unique for that subset only, that is to say, other points in the space could yield the same mean therefore mean is not a unique identifier. Could anyone tell me of a unique measure that could describe the points without being number of points dependent?

Comment: `without being number of points dependent` - so basically you are trying to store the information of possibly infinitely many points in memory of fixed size? I guess that won't work.

Comment: If the points are randomly distributed then no, there is no way to uniquely encode their positions in fewer than `c*|s|`  bits of information, where `c` is some constant.  It's another matter if they are not randomly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

In short - it is impossible (as you would achieve infinite noiseless compression). You have to either have varied length representation (or fixed length with length being proportional to maximum number of points) or dealing with "collisions" (as your mapping will not be injective). In the first scenario you simply can store coordinates of each point. In the second one you approximate your point clouds with more and more complex descriptors to balance collisions and memory usage, some posibilities are:

- storing mean and covariance (so basically perofming maximum likelihood estimation over Gaussian families)
- performing some fixed-complexity density estimation like Gaussian Mixture Model or training a generative Neural Network
- use set of simple geometrical/algebraical properties such as:

  - number of points
  - mean, max, min, median distance between each pair of points
  - etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any subset can be identified by a bit mask of length `ceiling(lg(x))`, where bit *i* is 1 if the corresponding element belongs to the subset. There is no fixed-length representation that is not a function of *x*.

**EDIT**

I was wrong. [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is a good way to perform dimensionality reduction for this problem, but it won't work for some sets.

***However***, you can *almost* do it. Where "*almost*" is formally defined by the [**Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma), which states that for a given large dimension *N*, there exists a much lower dimension *n*, and a linear transformation that maps each point from *N* to *n*, while keeping the Euclidean distance between every pair of points of the set within some error ***ε*** from the original. Such linear transformation is called the JL Transform.

In other words, your problem is only solvable for sets of points where each pair of points are separated by at least ***ε***. For this case, the JL Transform gives you one possible solution. Moreover, there exists a relationship between *N*, *n* and ***ε*** (see the [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma)), such that, for example, if *N*=100, the JL Transform can map each point to a point in 5D (*n*=5), **an uniquely identify each subset**, if and only if, the minimum distance between any pair of points in the original set is at least ~2.8 (i.e. the points are *sufficiently* different).

Note that *n* depends only on *N* and the minimum distance between any pair of points in the original set. It does not depend on the number of points *x*, so it is a solution to your problem, albeit some constraints.

Comment: Hi Diego, Could you forward me to the proof ? @Diego

Comment: @Jawad. Actually, it was easy for me to find a counterexample to my PCA intuition. See my edited answer for a more formal solution.

Comment: HI @Diego I read a little on JL and it seems that it does depend on the number of points as per the following definition taken from the following paper http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/papers/jl.pdf  (A result of Johnson and Lindenstrauss [13] shows that a set of n points in high
dimensional Euclidean space can be mapped into an O(log n/e^2
) dimensions. Doesn't this mean its dependent on x and not N?